Android: send local notification from background
I'm trying to implement custom call screen when app receive certain push notification.
When I have all the data avalable, I'm trying to raise local notification while app is still in background.
NB: it's a .NET code for MAUI, but it's basically a complete copycat of Android API, so should be readable for Java programmers.
void RegisterNotification(string cid, string title){
.......
var clickIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));
clickIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop | ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
clickIntent.PutExtra("field1thatneeded", "abcde");

var pendingIntentFlags = (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.S) ? PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent | PendingIntentFlags.Immutable : PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent;
var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, activityId, clickIntent, pendingIntentFlags);

.......

var notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this, AppConstants.CallChannelID)
   .SetAutoCancel(false)
   .SetOngoing(true)
   .SetContentTitle("Incoming call")
   .SetContentText(title)
   .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
   .SetStyle(Notification.CallStyle.ForIncomingCall(incomingCaller, rejectPendingIntent, answerPendingIntent))
   .SetCategory(Notification.CategoryCall);

var notification =notificationBuilder.Build();

#if ANDROID29_0_OR_GREATER
            StartForeground(notificationID, notification, Android.Content.PM.ForegroundService.TypePhoneCall);
#else
            StartForeground(notificationID, notification    );
#endif
}

Creating call notification right away not possible before any activity is attached, I cannot get PendingIntent (Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.UserHandle android.content.Context.getUser()' on a null object reference) or feed builder with required resources (Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference / Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.UserHandle android.content.Context.getUser()' on a null object reference )
The only solution I found is to create a Service:
[Service(ForegroundServiceType = Android.Content.PM.ForegroundService.TypePhoneCall, Exported = false)] //this attribute fills up AndroidManifest

internal class DroidCallService: Service
{
public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, [GeneratedEnum] StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
{
    if (intent.Action == "START_SERVICE")
    {
        var callID = intent.GetStringExtra("call_id");
        var name = intent.GetStringExtra("call_title");
        RegisterNotification(callID, name);
    }
    else if (intent.Action == "STOP_SERVICE")
    {
        StopForeground(StopForegroundFlags.Remove);
        StopSelfResult(startId);
    }

    return StartCommandResult.NotSticky;
}
}

When app is unloaded, all this work fine on Androids 11 and older, but since new restrictions of foreground services run, I get error on starting a service:
            Intent startService = new Intent(ctx, typeof(DroidCallService));
            startService.SetAction("START_SERVICE");

            startService.PutExtra("call_id", callID);
            startService.PutExtra("call_title", name);
            
#if ANDROID26_0_OR_GREATER
            ctx.StartForegroundService(startService); // ERROR!
#else
            ctx.StartService(startService);
#endif


Android.App.ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException:
startForegroundService() not allowed due to mAllowStartForeground
false

and

Android.App.BackgroundServiceStartNotAllowedException: Not allowed to
start service Intent { act=START_SERVICE
cmp=com.company.app/crc646332b1bcddc0e22c.DroidCallService
(has extras) }: app is in background

I saw multiple recommendations like asking user to skip battery optimization, using alarm clock or calendar etc, but it's all like "quirky" solutions.
Task is simple: background instance needs to run a foreground service. What is the proper way to do it and how?

When your app receives the push notification, you can first start the app first, and then send the local notifications.

@JessieZhang-MSFT how to do it in background? Can you elaborate, please, and add a small example, if possible.

I popped local notification using manager.notify(), but it doesn't support callstyle, so I'd like to know how to run foreground services in the future.

Apps that target Android 12 (API level 31) or higher can't start foreground services while running in the background, except for a few special cases. If an app tries to start a foreground service while the app is running in the background, and the foreground service doesn't satisfy one of the exceptional cases, the system throws a ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException.
Exemptions from background start restrictions:

Your app transitions from a user-visible state, such as an activity.
Your app can start an activity from the background, except for the
case where the app has an activity in the back stack of an existing
task.
Your app receives a high-priority message using Firebase Cloud
Messaging.
The user performs an action on a UI element related to your app. For
example, they might interact with a bubble, notification, widget, or
activity.
Your app invokes an exact alarm to complete an action that the user
requests.
Your app is the device's current input method.
Your app receives an event that's related to geofencing or activity
recognition transition.
After the device reboots and receives the ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED,
ACTION_LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED, or ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED intent
action in a broadcast receiver.

For more information, please check: Restrictions on starting a foreground service from the background.
